# How to package a python script with my java program?

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, dependency-injection, web-crawler

So, I'm writing a program(mostly for practice, kind of for future convenience) that will show a java front-end when run, and depending on the input, will use a python script to crawl and interpret a webpage, then send the interpreted data back to java to format for the front end. I'm sure I can get this running on my own computer, but when I want to distribute my program for my friends to use, how can I ensure my java program, mainProgram.jar can find my python code, script_x.py. Is there a way I can assure my python script will be supported. I've read that there are ways to include the necessary runtimes and such with your program when you build it, but would it still interact the same way with my java program if it was bundled with it's dependencies? I can provide some sample code soon, but it's still a work in progress, as I don't have the python script finished yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a link https://bytes.com/topic/python/insights/949995-three-ways-run-python-programs-java

use **Jython**  (compiles to java byte code)        https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jython

distributing Jython applications: https://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/DistributingJythonScripts